# Simple recursion convertion

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm new to programing and I'm trying to write this loop:

```
int x,n,pro=1;
cin>>n>>x;

for (int i=2; i<n+1; i++)
{
    pro=pro*x + i;
}
cout<<pro;
```

as a recursive function. I think `if (n==2) return x+n;` is the bottom of the recursion , but i don't know how to do the next step right. Any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion for this case? It won't be more efficient that what you have, if you should think so. Is it a homework task, so you have to do so?

Comment: Yes it is for homework,that's why I have to do it using recursion. But thanks to @NPE I think I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hint:

Assume that you know the solution for `n-1`. Ponder how you can use it to compute the solution for `n`.

Comment: I think i got it . Thanks! I think this works perfectly :
      
     int rec(int x,int n)
        {
          if (n==2)
            return x+n;
           else
            return rec(x,n-1)*x+n;
          }